# Qual a maneira simples de criar um WebService Rest a partir de um projeto Java Web Dynanic já existente?

Tags: java, web-service, hibernate, rest, tomcat

Fala galera

Sou iniciante no mundo do java e criei projeto Web Dynamic onde uso o Hibernate, PrimeFaces e TomCat. Tudo está funcionando, telas, cadastros(CRUD) e coisa e tal. Só que agora quero transformar-lo em um webservice para que eu possa consumir os dados através de uma app Android.
Já virei e revirei o Google e achei bastante coisa, com várias abordagens , usando varias frameworks diferentes. Isso embaralho bastante a minha cabeça e não sei por onde começar, o que usar. Então, gostaria de saber se alguem me da uma luz por onde começar.

Comment: Conforme está respondido, é interessante usar algum framework que resolva essas questões para vc. Parece que você já está adiantado no seu projeto, mas caso tenha um tempinho, veja o framework com o qual trabalho. Temos uma ferramenta que baseado neste framework gerará para você todo o CRUD a partir de sua classe POJO, inclusive para serviços Rest: http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/tools/nimble/1.2.1/html/eclipsesamplerest.html

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o Spring Framework, rapito, pratico, facil de implementar e muito uitil.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Caso queira algo mais otimizado para hibernate, eu desenvolvi uma biblioteca que ja implementa muita coisa.

https://github.com/KaynanCoelho/generic-repository